# Rails ActiveRecord: Looking for a db agnostic version of this statement

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a migration that executes this against a mysql server:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update 'comments' set 'slug' = NULL;")`

The purpose of this statement is to remove the value of "slug" for each row.
The table has millions of rows in it and is very slow when using ruby to do something like `Comment.each...`

Is there a way to rewrite this query in a way that it is db agnostic OR at minimum works OK between MySQL and postgresql?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Comment.update_all(:slug => nil)
```

This generates the query `UPDATE "comments" SET "slug" = NULL`

You can also do batch updates on scopes and conditions.  For examples, you can have:

```
Comment.where(:some_attribute => "some_value").update_all(:slug => nil)
```

That would produce `UPDATE "comments" SET "slug" = NULL WHERE (some_attribute = 'some_value')`

Comment: Good lord, how the hell did i over look that.  I feel ashamed and i will select this as the correct answer.  Thank you!!

Comment: +1 but note that MySQL recognizes double-quotes as identifier delimiters only if you `SET SQL_MODE='ANSI'` or `'ANSI_QUOTES'`  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: Well, the thing is, this is the SQL that is being generated for the active record adapter that I'm using, which, for the purposes of demonstration, is the sqlite3 adapter.  The beauty of Rails is that writing queries in an agnostic manner, as I have shown, is that they will be executed properly by any underlying adapter.  Thank for you the +1!